# Can't connect to database using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sqlps

I'm having issues with `sqlps` in my PowerShell script. I'm trying to select rows from a table and save them to a `.csv` file.

The query is

```
$TABLE="events"

Import-Module sqlps
$SQLquery='SELECT * FROM dbo.$TABLE'
$result=invoke-sqlcmd -query $SQLquery -HostName LOCALHOST -Password test -Username test
$result |export-csv c:\TEST.csv -notypeinformation
```

I get this error:

```
invoke-sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'test'.
At line:6 char:9
+ $result=invoke-sqlcmd -query $SQLquery -HostName LOCALHOST -Password  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management. 
   PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

invoke-sqlcmd : 
At line:6 char:9
+ $result=invoke-sqlcmd -query $SQLquery -HostName LOCALHOST -Password  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Could anyone be able to help?

Comment: Take a look at Sql Server's log file. It will contain more detailed an error message.

Comment: Single quotes for the `$SQLQuery` variable mean that it literally looks for `$TABLE`, not the `events` table I think you meant. Oh, and the password is probably wrong, I didn't read that bit properly!

Comment: Check by adding `Write-Host $SQLQuery`, that'll show you what the variable contains

Comment: Where do you specify the database to which you connect? Are you connecting to a specific SQL Server instance ?

Comment: when i use write-host it returns SELECT * FROM dbo.$TABLE. cool thanks alot. lemme try fix that quick

Comment: ok so changed the single quotes to double quotes and now its getting the variable in the query :) thanks @mjsqu

Comment: Where's the database located? The example you're running assumes the database is on the same machine that the code is running on. If that's correct then the credentials must be wrong. Also the `-Database` switch is usually required as @DavidBrabant said

Comment: ok so the issue was that even tho i had a seperate user on sql auth, the db only allowed windows authentication. thanks for telling me about the logs. didnt know that they logged login errors aswell

Comment: But now im getting a permission error when i try write the result to csv. any reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

So the main issue was the query needed to be in "" quotes not '' quotes and the server needs to be told to explicitly allow Microsoft account logins and SQL logins. even if you have a user setup for sql login. the option is under properties/security/server authentication.

Im leaving this answer here for if anyone ever runs into this beginner issue as i have. Thanks for the help from the community to get this sorted so quickly